# Как поставить size для FlowTextView?

Tags: android, java

Есть либа FlowTextView, как для неё поставить в xml размер шрифта текста, в коде писать не могу, потому что у меня 3 Layout под разные экраны. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. В библиотеке баг. Размер шрифта можно выставить только из кода, либо же пофиксить самому этот баг.

Comment: @metalurgus, Я видел код, как поставить программно, но у меня layout и large-layout, мне надо для одного один размер поставить для другого другой размер, в это и вся проблема.

Comment: @xTIGRx, и я видел, по этому я и ответил. Библиотека предусматривает установку через XML, но она не работает...

Comment: Вообщем подскажите мне пожалуйста, как добавить пользовательские атрибуты в xml view?

Comment: @xTIGRx, в коде получай размер из values | values-large